# How to convert list of dictionary values in python to a string and write on seprate cells of a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to write a dictionary on a csv file in Python.
I want the output to be like this:

```
    key1    key2
     4       3
     2       1
     3
```

but the output is like this:

```
    key1    key2
   ['4']   ['3']
   ['2']   ['1']
   ['3']
```

I'm using this code to write dictionary on csv files:

```
        my_file_path = os.path.join(filePath, 'MyDictionary.csv')
        with open(my_file_path,'w', newline='') as csv_file:
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, my_data.keys())
            csv_writer.writeheader()
            csv_writer.writerow(my_data)
```

I couldn't find my answer in the archive.
How can I convert the list of values in a way that it is written as a string on a csv file?

Comment: What is stored in your dictionary?  Can you show an example of its contents?

Comment: my_keys = [['key1','key1','key2'],['key3','key4'],['key4','key4'],['key5']]

my_values = ['1','2','3','4']

Comment: They're both lists, not dictionaries.  Can you show the contents of my_data just before the snippet of code you included executes?

Comment: I have a dictionary which has the keys and values like the above, and I call a function to write the keys and values on a csv file. the body of the program just calls this function. The output has brackets since when I build the dictionary I use this code:     if not my_terms[list_index][term_index] in my_dic:
     my_dic.setdefault(my_terms[list_index][term_index],[]).append(my_docid[list_index])
    elif not my_docid[list_index] in my_dic[my_terms[list_index][term_index]]:
     my_dic[my_terms[list_index][term_index]].append(my_docid[list_index])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import csv,os
>>> my_data = {'key1': [4,2,3], 'key2': [3,1]}
>>> filePath='.'
>>> my_file_path = os.path.join(filePath, 'MyDictionary.csv')
>>> with open(my_file_path,'w',, newline = '') as csv_file:
...     keys = sorted(my_data.keys()) #ensure key1 is before key2
...     csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
...     csv_writer.writerow(keys)
...     num_loops = max([len(v) for k,v in my_data.iteritems()])
...     for idx in range(0,num_loops):
...         row = []
...         for k in keys:
...             to_append = my_data[k][idx] if len(my_data[k])>idx else ''
...             row.append(to_append)
...         csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Output file:

```
key1    key2
4       3
2       1
3
```

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work with iteritems. I want the output key and values to be stored in separate cells.

Comment: do you want a one-line key: value1, value2, ... ?

Comment: I want to use the csv file to merge the key and values later, so any format of output which makes the merging easier would be proper either in one line or in a column.

Comment: I changed the delimiter = '\t' to ','. Now it works but it inserts an extra empty row after the key rows. How can I solve that?

Comment: I changed : open(my_file_path ,'w') as csv_file: to open(my_file_path ,'w' , newline = '') as csv_file: and iteritems to items and now it works, Thank you :)

Comment: your changes, to complete the answers, are: 1- the open function, 2- csv.writer function? with these changes have we fixed your problem?